# How to know that emited event is subscribed and action been taken or miss? (Angular6)

Tags: angular, observable

Using Angular 6 I have Shared Message Service. which emit (Send Message). There are subscriber who have to catch this event, If those subscriber component are loaded. How could from emiting point I know that my message been captured. Is there any recommended best practice.
The sample I am using for this purpose is:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

There is one way communication between `Observer` ans `Subscriber`. `Observer` will notify all its `Subscriber` and forgets it. So there is no direct way to notify the `Observer` that  `Subscriber` had listened and acted on it.

If you need to handle such kind of scenario then you re-design the communication structure.

Comment: Well what my point is that how could I know that my request have been missed?

Comment: Important is when and where you want to check if the request is missed.

Comment: well using the stated example I could set such missing info on shared service/MessageService get method. I want that messageservice know that fired event have been handled or missed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using component `@Input()` `@Output()` is a good way to implement subscription pattern. Generally speaking, you have Angular services and Observables exactly for that purpose.

The component itself should not worry about whether or not an event has been processed or not.

Comment: There could be a scenario. Let suppose the event emitter are button and listner are forms action. So if no form loaded it mean event will miss if emited. in such case I might show some message or take any action.

Comment: Xinan the sample as mentioned in question is explicitly about Angular Service. Which is shared service and used for publish subscribe scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite get what exactly you want to achieve. For publish/subscribe pattern, the publisher (your service) should not worry about whether or not the published event has been proceeded or not in any ways. It's the subscriber's job to decide what to do with the published content. Thus the publisher just need to focus on publishing things to avoid make the code logic over complicated. Perhaps you can try to think things from another angle? There are indeed workarounds, but from your question you said you want the Best Practice. Then my own opinion would be - don't do that.